# How to add required asterisk in a custom control?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using angular 6 to create a custom component which contains a custom form control. So far, I've implemented `ControlValueAccessor` in my component.

My custom control is a simple `MatSelect` component from Angular Material. I want to show the asterisk (`*`) for when that control is required.

So far, I've got the custom control to work, but adding the `required` attribute to the component doesn't add the asterisk to my control!

```html
<app-provinces formControlName="projectProvince" required></app-provinces>
```

Should I define an `@Input` variable for it and handle it manually, or should it be done automatically?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would an asterisk magically appear where you want it to appear if you have not added any code in your component to do that?

Comment: Well, I assume it is a form control as another ones !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should add a `required` `@Input()` to your component.

Something like this:

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row" [ngClass]="{
                    'has-danger': formGroup.controls[formControlName].invalid && formGroup.controls[formControlName].touched,
                    'has-success': formGroup.controls[formControlName].valid && formGroup.controls[formControlName].touched,
                    'has-no-action': formGroup.controls[formControlName].untouched
                                }">
        <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12" [for]="formControlId">
            {{formControlLabel}}
            <span *ngIf="isRequired" class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <select placeholder="place_holder_text" [disabled]="disabled" [class]="formControlName" [id]="formControlId" [data]="formControlItems"  (click)="setAsTouched()" (valueChanged)="store($event)"></select>
            <div class="form-control-feedback">{{formControlErrorText || 'Required Field May Not Be Empty'}}</div>
            <span class="m-form__help">{{formControlHelpText}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Component:

```ts
@Input('required') isRequired: boolean;
```

Example usage:

```html
<select-form-control
    [required]="true"
    [group]="myFormGroup"
    label="Name"
    name="name"
    controlId="name"
    [inputItems]="array"
    helpText="Enter..."
    [value]="name"
    (valueChange)="someMethod($event)">
</select-form-control>
```